# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when export excel file using Maatwebsite

Tags: excel, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and PHP, just trying to export a table html to excel file, using this [Maatwebsite](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/)

Follow this [hdtuto](https://hdtuto.com/article/php-laravel-55-import-export-data-into-excel-and-csv-using-maatwebsite)

This is my function

```
public function exportFile($id){
                $products = DB::table('duan')
                ->whereIn('MaDA', $id)
                ->get();
                return \Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) use ($products) {
                            $excel->sheet('sheet name', function($sheet) use ($products)
                            {
                                $sheet->fromArray($products);
                            });

                })->download('xlsx');
        }
```

But I have the warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: could you dump products with `dd($products)` method ?  it may be null or something

Comment: like this `Route::get('export/{id}', function($id){
    $products = DB::table('duan')
                ->whereIn('MaDA', $id)
                ->get();
     dd($products);

});
`? I still get the 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' error

Comment: I see, but could you just dump products ? after the this query `$products = DB::table('duan')
                ->whereIn('MaDA', $id)
                ->get();` just say `dd($products)`

Comment: thank you, I know where is my fault, in `->whereIn('MaDA', $id)`, I have to insert [], like this `->whereIn('MaDA', [$id])`

Comment: seems so, because your query returns you null, I will add this as an answer may be help anothers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error because php couldn't find items (array or object) for iterate in foreach loop. There is a misspelling in your query and it causes to return you `null`

```
public function exportFile($id){
                $products = DB::table('duan')
                ->whereIn('MaDA', $id) // you need to put $id in array like [$id]
                ->get();

                return \Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) use ($products) {
                         $excel->sheet('sheet name', function($sheet) use ($products)
                            {
                                $sheet->fromArray($products);
                            });

                })->download('xlsx');
 }
```